# To be at the end of a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Help to understand the grammatical logic of having 'are' at the end of this sentence would be much appreciated:

> I am surprised at how well organized they are.

Comment: Let's approach the question from a different direction.  Is there a different way that you think the sentence could be phrased?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I understand there are better ways to phrase this sentence.  However, this is from a non-native English speaker who is trying to understand the logic of English grammar.  The sentence is not a question but the structure seems to be that of an indirect question.

Comment: This sentence is **fine**. John was surprised by how thin the puppies were.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is

> I am surprised at **how well organized they are**.

The part in bold is an exclamative content clause. It is a subordinate clause, complement of the preposition "at". It uses the interrogative word "how", but in an exclamative sense.

It could appear as a simple exclamation in a main clause...

> How well organized they are!

The word order is as in this reference:
[Cambridge.org Clause Types](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/clause-types)

> Exclamative clauses
> How + adjective or adverb + subject + verb
> *How beautiful that house was!*

(Partial, edited quotation ... check the link.)

So, that's why it ends with the verb "are".
It's surprising how simple it **is**.

Comment: Thanks, Jack - that makes perfect sense.

Comment: nickfish, if you like an answer to a question you've asked, at least vote it up. If you're satisfied with it and don't want anyone else to give another answer, then accept it.

Comment: I disagree that it’s exclamative here. After all it’s exactly the same construct, with exactly the same meaning, as in both *I wonder how well organized they are* and *When you get there, please check how well organized they are*.